# Components library for Day CQ

Tags: adobe, components, aem, day-cq

I'm developing a site on Adobe Day CQ. My site should consist of many different components that can not be found in the standard library Day CQ. Are there any third-party component libraries for this CMS, or will I need to create them yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly not as many as one might expect--at least at present.  It certainly seems like fertile ground for a startup.  But here are a few if they happen to mesh with your particular needs:

- Video component - http://www.brightcove.com/en/partners/cq5  and http://blog.brightcove.com/en/2011/12/brightcove-integrates-video-cloud-adobe%E2%80%99s-cq5-cms and http://coresecure.com/bc-cq5-component/
- Google maps component - http://blogs.adobe.com/livecyclepost/2011/09/google-maps-component-for-adep-wemcq5/
- Adobe third-party references - http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/developing/developers_getting_started.html#Third%20Party%20Libraries

There are consultants as well you could tap to create custom components.  They likely have some libraries they have developed, but not (yet?) packaged for resale that they may be able to leverage:

- http://www.headstandmedia.com/what-we-do/cms/adobe-cq5/cq5-development/
- http://www.ensemble.com/expertise/digitalmarketing/cq5.shtml